# Unable to load all records in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jqgrid

I am not able to bind all rows in JQgrid. It is binding only 2272 rows.Even i have used maxJsonLength as well but it is still not showing all data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
 
 you need to use `loadonce: true` to load all records.

Comment: I am using same as well but unable to understand why only 2272 records are loading.